# Filling generated dynamic data in a ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here the idea is to fill in the items in a list and use that list to display on GUI.

So, in `_MyAppState` I have filled in dummy items in the list:

```
final items = List<Vehicle>.generate(
    100,
    (i) => i % 6 == 0
        ? (Vehicle(
              'qqq',
              ['111', '222'],))
        : (Vehicle(
              'sss',
              ['333', '444'],))
  );
```

Then I have attempted to show this list in the Column of the same class.

Nothing is being displayed. **Please guide where am I going wrong.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,),);

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> 
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) 
  {
    final items = List<Vehicle>.generate(
    100,
    (i) => i % 6 == 0
        ? (Vehicle(
              'qqq',
              ['111', '222'],))
        : (Vehicle(
              'sss',
              ['333', '444'],))
     );

    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: vehicles.length,

        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return new ExpansionTile(

            title: new Text(vehicles[i].title, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),

            children: <Widget>[
              new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, 
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, 
                children: _buildExpandableContent( items[i] )
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildExpandableContent(Vehicle vehicle) {
    List<Widget> columnContent = [];

    for (String content in vehicle.contents)
      columnContent.add(
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text(content, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
        ),
      );

    return columnContent;
  }
}

class Vehicle {
  final String title;
  List<String> contents = [];

  Vehicle(this.title, this.contents);
}

List<Vehicle> vehicles = [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you create a dummy list named `items`, but you're using the `vehicles` list instead. Just change it everywhere and you're done.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
        home: new MyApp(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = List<Vehicle>.generate(
      100,
      (i) => i % 6 == 0
          ? (Vehicle(
              'qqq',
              ['111', '222'],
            ))
          : (Vehicle(
              'sss',
              ['333', '444'],
            )),
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length, // Use items instead of vehicles here
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return new ExpansionTile(
            title: new Text(
              items[i].title, // and here again
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
            children: <Widget>[
              new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: _buildExpandableContent(items[i])),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildExpandableContent(Vehicle vehicle) {
    List<Widget> columnContent = [];

    for (String content in vehicle.contents)
      columnContent.add(
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text(
            content,
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
        ),
      );

    return columnContent;
  }
}

class Vehicle {
  final String title;
  List<String> contents = [];

  Vehicle(this.title, this.contents);
}

List<Vehicle> vehicles = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use a `Column` as child of [ExpansionTile](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/expansion-tile-in-flutter-d2b7ba4a1f4b). Get rid of it and just do this:

```
ExpansionTile(

            title: Text(vehicles[i].title, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),

            children: _buildExpandableContent(items[i])
          )
```

You should also remove `new` keyword for more readability.